# New Connection in MySQL Server is unable to Start

Tags: mysql, startup

I made a new Connection and then on selecting it, I am unable to Start MySQL Server using Workbench.
I am getting following message:

```
2014-09-23 18:31:45 - Workbench will use cmd shell commands to start/stop this instance
2014-09-23 18:31:47 - Starting server...
2014-09-23 18:31:52 - Server start done.
2014-09-23 18:31:53 - Checking server status...
2014-09-23 18:31:53 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-09-23 18:31:53 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
2014-09-23 18:31:53 - Assuming server is not running
2014-09-23 18:31:53 - Checking server status...
2014-09-23 18:31:53 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-09-23 18:31:53 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
2014-09-23 18:31:53 - Assuming server is not running
```

What is the issue, can anybody tell me?

Comment: Did you try connecting to the server by any other means? (like command line client for example)

Comment: this error occurs only when i change username and password, otherwise it works fine.

Comment: probably those credentials are not registered...

Comment: @thiagomarini how do i register them ?

Comment: You can add new users through SQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Or you can add the user through any MySQL client software, like Workbench.